# cleaning up ^blocks

Tags: ios, ios5, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

The method below is from a [github](https://github.com/kyleroche/Professional_iOS_AugmentedReality) repository for the book *Professional iOS Augmented Reality book* (Apress).

There isn't any code in the overall `UIViewController`-based example which deals with clean up. The CoreImage face detection routine called here could take a few seconds to complete.

What happens if the user causes a change resulting in this viewController disappearing? I understand the ^block is retained by the queue, Is this a case where sending a message to nil (when the face detection routine returns) is actually a benefit?

```
- (IBAction)detectFacialFeatures:(id)sender {

    self.detectingView.hidden = NO;
    self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        CIImage *image = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:[FACE_IMAGES objectAtIndex:self.currentIndex]];

        NSString *accuracy = self.useHighAccuracy ? CIDetectorAccuracyHigh : CIDetectorAccuracyLow;
        NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:accuracy forKey:CIDetectorAccuracy];
        CIDetector *detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace context:nil options:options];

        NSArray *features = [detector featuresInImage:image];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self drawImageAnnotatedWithFeatures:features];
        });    
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dispatch_async()` copies the block, because it will keep it beyond its declaration scope.  All objects referenced in block are retained when it is copied.  So, assuming that the viewController to which you're referring is `self`, it won't be `nil`. It will have been retained for the life of the block.

Comment: does this mean that any views or other properties of the retained viewController are also retained? I ask because I was wondering about memory leaks or the VC trying to reference a view which no longer exists.

Comment: If the view controller has retained other objects (perhaps with `strong` properties), then those will also stick around, along with whatever they retain, etc. Of course, the view controller code may release things, for example in `-didReceiveMemoryWarning`, and those may go away. This is standard reference-counted memory management. There's no leak because the block will eventually be released and it will release whatever it's retaining.